# Timestamp and GREP

Tags: r

I have date/time information that is structured as such

```
[623] "2014-05-11 16:23:32.469755-07:00" "2014-05-11 17:23:17.249083-07:00"
[625] "2014-05-11 17:23:23.388797-07:00" "2014-05-11 17:23:35.560757-07:00"
[627] "2014-05-11 18:23:08.666497-07:00" "2014-05-11 18:23:16.361057-07:00"
[629] "2014-05-11 19:23:05.011185-07:00" "2014-05-11 19:23:52.680621-07:00"
[631] "2014-05-11 20:23:08.115774-07:00" "2014-05-11 23:07:08.212175-07:00"
[633] "2014-05-11 23:09:27.224237-07:00" "2014-05-11 23:10:08.484308-07:00"
[635] "2014-05-11 23:10:26.716268-07:00" "2014-05-11 23:47:51.984684-07:00"
[637] "2014-05-11 23:55:23.823294-07:00" "2014-05-16 01:23:17.320829-07:00"
[639] "2014-05-16 11:23:50.363459-07:00" "2014-05-16 11:23:58.084398-07:00"
[641] "2014-05-16 12:23:01.112621-07:00" "2014-05-16 12:23:53.391903-07:00"
[643] "2014-05-16 15:23:54.859097-07:00" "2014-05-16 18:23:13.171668-07:00"
[645] "2014-05-16 18:23:36.692394-07:00" "2014-05-16 18:23:54.121722-07:00"
[647] "2014-05-16 19:23:38.887839-07:00" "2014-05-16 19:23:44.585220-07:00"
[649] "2014-05-16 19:23:53.281597-07:00" "2014-05-16 20:23:26.042912-07:00"
[651] "2014-05-16 20:23:30.612085-07:00" "2014-05-16 20:23:51.244658-07:00"
[653] "2014-05-16 23:00:58.867016-07:00" "2014-05-16 23:03:13.503560-07:00"
[655] "2014-05-16 23:09:03.804929-07:00" "2014-05-16 23:10:35.960517-07:00"
[657] "2014-05-16 23:14:59.971752-07:00" "2014-05-16 23:19:58.798553-07:00"
```

How do I write a grep to select only the elements between 11 PM and 3:59 AM?

Comment: Have you tried %between% ?

Comment: Can you tell me how I'd use it?

Comment: Does the `"2014-05-11 16:23:32.469755-07:00"` signifies from 4:23 pm to 7 am? or is it 4:23 pm to 7 pm?

Comment: `x[as.POSIXlt(x)$hour >= 23 | as.POSIXlt(x)$hour < 4]`